# How I can set FileName after click Upload a File from local PC?

Tags: c#, fileopendialog

I have some short code:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "NHC|*.nhc";
    openFileDialog1.Title = @"test.nhc";

    OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openfiledialog.ShowHelp = true;
    openfiledialog.FileName = "test.nhc";
    openfiledialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

I want to set the FileName in `OpenFileDialog`.
For example: I have a web app and I click <kbd>Upload</kbd> to upload a file from the local PC. The `OpenFileDialog` PopUp does open. Now I want to set the FileName to `test.nhc` in the field `FileName` (Windows window) and click "Open".

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Let me understand your question. You want, when you press an UPLOAD button on an WEB application/page, choose what is the filename that appears in the system owned open file dialog?

Comment: I want to upload a file from local PC. On layout is button UPLOAD. Then I want to sort files to .nhc extension, set test.nhc in FILENAME windows window and Click OPEN. Next validate that new version .nhx is on web app (e.g. using by Webdruver).

Comment: It is quite similar like in Zamzar.com, when You click [Choose], windows pop up dialog, then You put File Name and Click Open. I want to automate these steps in C#.

Comment: It was quite simple sollution:  Thread.Sleep(500);
            SendKeys.SendWait(RepoFiles.File_Name);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            SendKeys.SendWait(RepoButtons.Enter);

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the name before or after clicking?
You should define this name in PageLoad, for example. Not at Click.

```
OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
            openfiledialog.FileName = "test.nhc";
         }
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
          openfiledialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the event for open file ok button. First you need to create a Stream object and then an event that will happen in DialogResult.OK situation.

Here is an example from microsoft

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream = null;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "NHC|*.nhc";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Title = @"test.nhc";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (myStream)
                        {
                            // Insert code to read the stream here.
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }



  
        }
    }
```